# Concatenation of files with different codecs attributes?

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, video-conversion

It shows in the ffmpeg documentation the following code example:

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -i input2.webm \ 
-filter_complex "[0:v:0] [0:a:0] [1:v:0] [1:a:0] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" \
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" <encoding options> output.mkv
```

It says a little below the example: "As you can infer from this example, multiple types of input are supported, and anything readable by ffmpeg should work. The inputs have to be of the same frame size, and a handful of other attributes have to match."

Does anyone know what attributes need to be the same? Below are my two files I am trying to merge and I don't know if it's even possible given the many differences in attributes despite these files both being of .avi format:

(Sidenote: file2.avi was looped from an image and I would be open to concatenating a looped image directly to file1.avi as well).

```
ffmpeg -i file2.avi
ffmpeg version 2.6.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.6.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libxvid --enable-vda
  libavutil      54. 20.100 / 54. 20.100
  libavcodec     56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavformat    56. 25.101 / 56. 25.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 11.102 /  5. 11.102
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, avi, from 'file2.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.25.101
  Duration: 00:05:00.09, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 389 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg2video (Main) (mpg2 / 0x3267706D), yuv420p(tv), 1000x700 [SAR 1:1 DAR 10:7], 244 kb/s, 47.95 fps, 23.98 tbr, 47.95 tbn, 47.95 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp2 (P[0][0][0] / 0x0050), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
At least one output file must be specified
```

file1.avi was converted from a .mts raw video file.

```
ffmpeg -i file1.avi
ffmpeg version 2.6.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.6.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libxvid --enable-vda
  libavutil      54. 20.100 / 54. 20.100
  libavcodec     56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavformat    56. 25.101 / 56. 25.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 11.102 /  5. 11.102
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, avi, from 'file1.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.25.101
  Duration: 00:16:28.06, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6889 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv420p, 1440x1080 [SAR 4:3 DAR 16:9], 6616 kb/s, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 59.94 tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: ac3 ([0] [0][0] / 0x2000), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s
At least one output file must be specified
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The pixel dimensions need to be the same for the concatenate filter to work.

In your case, you have some options: either crop, scale, or pad one of the files so that the pixel dimensions are the same.

Note - I haven't had to concatenate with audio before, so I'll show you how to do it below without audio.  You should be able to play around with the command below in conjunction with the [audio info here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate) .... At least until someone more knowledgeable answers.

```
ffmpeg -i file1.avi -i file2.avi -filter_complex "[1:v]pad=1140:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[p1];[0:v][p1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[out]" -map [out] ....... [transcode settings]
```